# Delete Item in a Linked List - Program Does Not Work

Tags: c

I have this function on my program that deletes a particular value on a linked list, such as:

> Value to be deleted: 8
>
> Linked List: 2 -> 9 -> 8 -> 3 -> 5 -> X
>
> List after removal of value: 2 -> 9 -> 3 -> 5 -> X

The problem is, it does not work as it is intended to. Below is my function's code:

```
void removeValue(DLList L, int value){
assert (L != NULL);
DLListNodeP curr = L->curr;
while (curr != NULL){
    if (curr->value == value){
        if (L->first == L->last){   // If there is only one item in the list
            L->curr = NULL;
            L->first = NULL;
            L->last = NULL;
            L->nitems = 0;
        }

        else if (L->curr->next == NULL){    // If current item is the last item on the list
            L->curr->prev->next = NULL;
            L->last = L->curr->prev;
            free (L->curr);
            L->last->next = NULL;
            L->curr = L->last;
            L->nitems--;
        }

        else if (L->curr->prev == NULL){ // If current item is the first item on the list
            L->curr = L->curr->next;
            free (L->curr->prev);
            L->curr->prev = NULL;
            L->first = L->curr;
            L->nitems--;
        }

        else {
            DLListNodeP next = L->curr->next;
            L->curr = NULL;
            L->curr = next;
            L->curr->prev->next = L->curr->next;
            L->curr->next->prev = L->curr->prev;
            L->nitems--;
        }

        L->curr = L->curr->next;
    }
    else {
        L->curr = L->curr->next;
    }
}

return; }
```

I've tried modifying the code, one part at a time, but still I can't make it work; I tried literally everything. Is there anything that I can do to make this code work? Thanks

Comment: `DLListNodeP curr = L->curr;` Should that be `DLListNodeP curr = L->first;` ?

Comment: "List after removal of value: 2 -> 9 -> 3 -> 5 -> X" is not demonstrated with posted  code.  Easier to help if you include a [MCVE]

Comment: "it does not work as it is intended" is of little value.  What was the result that differed from "2 -> 9 -> 3 -> 5 -> X".

Comment: @chux The list simply didn't change - nothing was deleted.

Comment: What was the result of using `DLListNodeP curr = L->first;`?  Note, without posting a [MCVE] this post will likely attract more DVs.

Comment: Note that the 1st `if()` and last `else` do not free memory -   that is a memory leak.

Comment: `L->curr = next;
            L->curr->prev->next = L->curr->next;
            L->curr->next->prev = L->curr->prev;` is certainly wrong.

Comment: Using `DLListNodeP curr = L->first;` doesn't make it work.

Comment: What's the problem with `L->curr = next; L->curr->prev->next = L->curr->next; L->curr->next->prev = L->curr->prev;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
DLListNodeP prev = L->curr, next = L->curr->next; // Check if curr exists
if (prev->value == value) {
   L->curr = next;
   return;
}

while (next != NULL){
   if (next->value == value) {
      prev->next = next->next;
      break;
   }
   prev = next;
   next = next->next;
}
```

Comment: "prev->next = next->next;" doesn't work (statement with no effect)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems more complex than it needs to be.

I'm not sure what `L->curr` is for since you already have `L->first`, `L->last`, and `L->nitems`.

Here's a refactored version that should work. Note that I didn't compile or test it, but it should give you a better starting place:

```
void
removeValue(DLList L, int value)
{
    DLListNodeP prev;
    DLListNodeP next;
    DLListNodeP curr;

    assert(L != NULL);

#if 0
    curr = L->curr;
#else
    curr = L->first;
#endif

    if (curr != NULL)
        prev = curr->prev;
    else
        prev = NULL;

    // remove all matching nodes
    for (;  curr != NULL;  curr = next) {
        next = curr->next;

        // skip to next item if _not_ a  match
        if (curr->value != value) {
            prev = curr;
            continue;
        }

        // adjust forward link of previous node
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;

        // adjust backward link of next node
        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = prev;

        // adjust head of list if removing first item
        if (L->first == curr)
            L->first = next;

        // adjust tail of list if removing last item
        if (L->last == curr)
            L->last = prev;

        L->nitems--;
        free(curr);
    }
}
```